# Как определить передан ли примитив в generic или же массив примитивов?

Tags: java, generics

Есть класс Property, он принимает примитив или же массив. Для корректного отображения массива в `toString()` нужно определить, массив ли T, или же просто примитив. Как определить?

```
public class Property<T> {
    private T propertyValue;

    public Property() {
    }

    public Property(T propertyValue) {
    set(propertyValue);
    }

    public T get() {
        return propertyValue;
    }

    public void set(T value) {
        this.propertyValue = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(propertyValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Примитив вы никогда не сможете использовать в дженериках. Это всегда объект.

Comment: Когда вы передаете примиты в женерик класс, то они заворачиваются в обьекты типа Integer,Float,Boolean и т.д.
А когда вы передаете массив примитивов, то они не заворачиваются ни во что, потому что массив - это есть объект.

Comment: @АртемФролов, не нужно исправлять код прямо в вопросе (тогда не понятно будет, в чем была проблема), и добавлять "решено" в заголовок тоже не нужно (достаточно отметить ответ принятым).

Comment: @insolor спасибо за поправки)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примитив вы никогда не сможете использовать на месте дженерика `Т`. Это всегда объект. Но если вы имеете ввиду, что хотите различать, например, объекты класса `Integer` и `Integer[]`, то можно поступить так:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    if (propertyValue.getClass().isArray()) {
        return Arrays.toString((T[])propertyValue);
    }
    return String.valueOf(propertyValue);
}
```

Comment: компилятор ругается что надо привести к 1 обертки примитива(

Comment: @АртемФролов, обновил ответ

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [D cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Comment: @АртемФролов, как вы используете этот объект в методе main?

Comment: все спасибо нашел проблему.

Comment: @АртемФролов, успехов! =)

Comment: загвоздка заключалась в том что cast в T[] делал обертку примитивов, а propertyValue был просто массив примитивов